# how to pull the value from the header and insert it into the link using JS Elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

How to pull the value from the header and insert it into the button link.

```
<script>

$('document').ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            let prop= 'https://examlp.com/PDFs/';
                let pr= $("#name").val(); //set the name value in the header css id
            window.location.href=prop+pr;
        
      return false;
    });
 });

</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<h1 id="headerID">ExampleName</h1>

<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        let base_url = 'https://example.com/PDFs/';
        let header_value = $("#headerID").text();
        let final_url = base_url + header_value;
        
        window.location.href = final_url;
        
        return false;
    });
});
```